Acceder a la url .mp3 de un archivo guardado en Google Drive para reproducirlo en <audio> tag HTML
Estoy tratando de conseguir entender cómo funciona la API de Google Drive para acceder a los archivos y poder interactuar con estos en nuestras páginas Web.
Encontré este caso en el que el colega buscaba hacer algo similar, pero con un <img>:
AÑADIENDO IMAGEN URL DESDE ARCHIVO EN DRIVE
Ahora, lo que yo estoy buscando es lo mismo, pero con un .MP3 y un tag audio.


<audio src="https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=18FBJpjrrM7v5xvhXp4Z5ZDiqkGJA-OZh" controls>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



Este es mi enlace del archivo MP3 subido en Drive:
https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=18FBJpjrrM7v5xvhXp4Z5ZDiqkGJA-OZh
Agradezco su ayuda :)

Luego de buscar un poco en la web, encontré este tutorial para habilitar la reproducción de medios.
Aplica tanto para videos, como para audios.
TUTORIAL DE COMO HABILITAR LA REPRODUCCION EXTERNA DE MEDIOS EN DRIVE
Espero que le sirva a otras personas :)

Hola, debes agregar la información esencial del enlace en la respuesta, ya que el enlace cuando deja de ser válido , hace que esta respuesta no sea válida, revisar [answer]

Las respuestas que solo tienen enlaces son, en general, consideradas de baja calidad. La sugerencia es que incluyas las partes esenciales para resolver el problema en la respuesta. Puedes dejar el link como información adicional, referencia o soporte.

Y cómo quieren que haga un paso a paso de todo lo que hay que hacer para generar la Api key, instalar la dependencia de Drive, etc (???)
